# My form in my rails app isn't capturing the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm making a rails app where I'm uploading a picture, got a few checkboxes to tick or not about the picture you upload, some text entry boxes and some drop down boxes. I've set default values for things not set. The form is capturing the picture and a few answers, but not everything and I'm not sure why

Here is the form in question:

```
<%= form_with(model: @painting, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if @painting.errors.any? %>
    <div>
      <% pluralize(@painting.errors.count, "error") %>
      <% @painting.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.id == 1 %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :river %>
    <%= form.check_box :river %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :mountains %>
    <%= form.check_box :mountains %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :cabin %>
    <%= form.check_box :cabin %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :guest %>
    <%= form.text_field :guest %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :startcolour, "Start Colour" %>
    <%= select_tag(:startcolour, options_for_select(['white', 'black', 'clear', 'acrylic black', 'grey', 'mixed', 'other'])) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :other %>
    <%= form.text_field :other %>
  </div>

<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :season %>
    <%= select_tag(:season, options_for_select([1, 2])) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :episode %>
    <%= select_tag(:episode, options_for_select([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :artwork %>
    <%= form.file_field :artwork %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is from the controller calling the form with default values:

```
 def new

    if current_user
      if current_user.profile
        @painting = Painting.new(river: false, mountains: false, cabin: false, startcolour: "white")
        @painting.save
      else
        redirect_to new_profile_path
      end
    else 
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
```

And here is where it goes in the controller after the form, essentially me connecting the back end so the profile user and the painting are linked:

```
  def create
    @painting = Painting.new(painting_params) 
    @painting.artwork.attach(params[:painting][:artwork])
    @profile = Profile.new 
    @profile.id = current_user.profile.id
    @profile.save
    @painting.profile_id = current_user.profile.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @painting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @painting, notice: 'Painting was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @painting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @painting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However after the painting is uploaded I'm finding no matter which user is signed it it always assigns the painting to user 2. It also isn't saving most of the info from the form other than the picture and the occasional tick box (even the ones I specified).

What I'm actually expecting is whoever signed in - their user id to be attached to the painting. And I'm wondering where the hell the data from my form has gone? Why isn't it saving? Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does guest field appears in generated html form ?

Comment: yes as a text box the user can write in

Comment: is it being passed to controller (and being updated ) ?

Comment: mmm i assume so? What would that look like if it was/wasn't??

Comment: You can use pry to have breakpoint to check?

Comment: i don't know what that means :/ sorry I'm kinda new to rails. How would I do that?

Comment: pry is a debugger gem for rails app.  Try using it to check  current user and params value. It will stop the execution at any point of code, you write `binding.pry`

Comment: oh interesting ok I'll have a look into that. Up until now I've just been putting in puts statements etc to see what the terminal spits out :P

Comment: Could you tell us what is your ```painting_params```?

Comment: @BrunoM it should be all the data from the form but when I'm saying to tell me what they are in the terminal is telling me that season and episode (and a few others) are unpermitted :/

Comment: It seems like you didn't permit it. In order to do that you are going to have something like this in your controller (after ```private```)
```def painting_params
    params.require(:painting).permit(:river, :mountains, :cabin, :startcolour) # and any other column that you want to pass from the html fields
  end
```

Comment: @B-M bam!! Thank you, solved! I migrated those last few columns after scaffolding so they didn't Auto generate like the others. Cheers :)

Comment: Not a problem. Since this solved your problem, I'm making an answer out of it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you didn't permit it. In order to do that you are going to have something like this in your controller:

```rb
private 

def painting_params 
  params.require(:painting).permit(:river, :mountains, :cabin, :startcolour) # and any other column that you want to pass from the html fields 
end
```